# MySQL 5.7 and SELECT DISTINCT JSON attributes

Tags: mysql, json

I need a help in selection. How I can get rows with unique attributes, for example I have 2 json strings in db.

1. `{"name":["name1"]};`
2. `{"name":["name2", "name1"]};`
3. `{"name":["name3", "name4"]};`
4. `{"name":["name3"]};`

If I try just `SELECT DISTINCT data->"$.name"` so I get all 2 strings, but I need to check every param and if some was before then don't show it.
Is it possible?

I want to get just 1 and 3 rows, because 2 and 4 contains names which we already have (I don't care about name2 in my case name2 equivalent name1).

Comment: Not sure I'm following. What result would you want to get for this sample data?

Comment: Just first string, for now I getting all 2, but if every string is {"name":["name1"]};
{"name":["name1"}; it returns only 1 string.  I need to check every param is unique in $.name

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "param". Is the whole name column a parameter, or is each string in the JSON array a param? In other words, should the output be ["name1"], ["name2,"name1"] or should it be ["name1"],["name2"]? Or maybe you want the output to be strings, not JSON? I suggest you edit your question to show the actual output you want.

Comment: So, I just wanna get string of json, if first has name1 - we take it, but if second string has name1 too -> exclude it from list.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to contribute this answer to the void. This will return all unique top-level JSON keys; unfortunately `{'test':1}` and `{'test':1, 'word':1}` will return two records, `test` and `test, word`. This may still be suitable for some.

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_KEYS(tags) as name FROM items WHERE JSON_LENGTH(tags) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_UNQUOTE(features->"$.name[0]") as name 
FROM data WHERE JSON_LENGTH(features->"$.name") = 1
```

So, I just took result where attr name has 1 item only. And that we can check for unique. It's not the best solution, but I don't have another yet)